# Spring Integration: http converter issue using application/octet-stream content type

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

I have this flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flow(){
    return IntegrationFlows.from(QueueMessageSink.INPUT)
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(QueueMessage.class))
        .<QueueMessage, DTOMessage> transform(queueMessage -> new DTOMessage(/* transform logic */))
        .handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST))
        .channel("nullChannel")
        .get();
}
```

Basically, I'm reading a message from a queue and posting it to a REST endpoint.

Messages in queue are arriving with Content-type application/octet-stream so I have configured my queue in the following way:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.my-queue.contentType=application/octet-stream
```

Message is correctly transformed from JSON to QueueMessage and from QueueMessage to DTOMessage, but I have the following exception when trying to POST the DTOMessage:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: HTTP request execution failed for URI; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.example.DTOMessage] and content type [application/octet-stream]
```

I think (maybe I'm wrong) that Http.outboundGateway is reading the content type application/octet-stream from headers of the Spring Integration Message.

What It would be the correct way to fix this? I guess that a possible solution is to change the content type to application/json, but I'm not sure if it is the simplest way (and I don't know how to do it).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that a possible solution is to change the content type to application/json

That is really a correct way to go, but you shouldn't do that on the `bindings`, but inside your flow. I think something like this should do the trick for you:

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h
                .defaultOverwrite(true)
                .header(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
.handle(Http.outboundGateway(uri).httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST))
```

Comment: That seems to work, thanks. I have another question. Is it right that transformation from JSON to QueueMessage? I mean, before the enrichHeaders step I have an inconsistent message where the payload is a Java Object and the content type is application/octet and I have to manually overwrite it, that sounds strange to me.

Comment: Because you convert *from* JSON *to* POJO, not vise versa. It's not because you have JSON converted to the `QueueMessage` and then you transform it into the `DTOMessage`, so, looks like we can't just pass your bytes directly to the `Http.outboundGateway()` assuming that it is a JSON. Anyway it looks like you have to override it anyway according your HTTP requirements...